# Find wordpress post by search term OR tag

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to write an query that should find a post by search-term or tag-name. But when i add the tag name the search stops working.

```
$mainQuery = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => array('coworker', 'post', 'page', 'news'),
    's' => sanitize_text_field($data['term']),
    'relation' => 'OR',
    'tag' => array(
        'tag' => sanitize_text_field($data['term'])
    )
));
```

What have i done wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. WP_Query does not accept the [relation parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#parameters), this is only accepted in the `tax_query` and `meta_query` arguments.
2. The [tag parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#tag-parameters) does not require you wrap your argument in an array, it accepts a variety of names, depending on what argument(s) you are passing.

Depending on your implementation, you likely need to run two queries and [merge the results](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130009/how-to-merge-two-queries-together), as you want either OR result.